# Serve HTML snapshot to Moz SEO bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, seo, user-agent, bots

I'm using Phantom to prerender dynamic pages on my website every day. I then wrote some code to check the user agent of a request and serve the prerendered HTML snapshot if the request is from a bot. My array of bots is:

```
var socialBots = [
  "facebookexternalhit/1.0", "facebookexternalhit/1.1", "FacebookExternalHit", 
  "twitterbot", "TwitterBot", "Twitterbot/1.0", 
  "LinkedInBot",
  "rogerBot", "rogerBot/1.0"
];
```

Then my nodeJS code (using Express) to listen for bots and serve snapshots:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){

  var userAgent = req.get("user-agent"), 
      socialBot = false;    

  for (i=0; i<socialBots.length; i++) { 
    if (userAgent.indexOf(socialBots[i]) > -1) {
      socialBot = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (socialBot) {
    //serve snapshot
  }

});
```

This works fine for Facebook and Twitter but the last line of the array `rogerBot` should be for Moz SEO and doesn't seem to work. Moz SEO didn't get my snapshots on it's last crawl. Have I just got the user agent wrong or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User Agent for RogerBot would be:

> rogerbot/1.0 (http://moz.com/help/pro/what-is-rogerbot-, rogerbot-crawler+shiny@moz.com)

You need to lowercase rogerBot to

> rogerbot